# fetch image from mongodb to website with angular6

Tags: html, angular, image, angular6

I'm working on my website and I'd like to fetch an image from my DB to the header of my website.

I have a customer ID and every customer has an different logo. Now I don't know how to display the logo with angular.

Here is my unfinished code:

Component which get the image by customer id:

```
logo: string;
companyName: string;

ngOnInit() {
    this.currentLang = this.translate.getDefaultLang();
    this.languages = this.translate.getLangs();

    this.activatedRoute.queryParams.subscribe((params: Params) => {
        const customerId = params["customerId"];
        if (customerId) {
            this.userService.getCustomer(customerId)
                .subscribe(customer => {
                    this.logo = customer.logo, this.companyName = customer.name
                });
        }
    });
}
```

And here I'd like to display the selected logo:

```
<div class="logo">
      <span class="logo-type"><img src="{{ customer.logo }}"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: are you getting any error in console?

Comment: <span class="logo-type"><img src="{{ logo }}"></span> try this

Comment: As Chellappan just wrote, you only have a class variable called `logo`, you should create a var for customer if you want to use it in the HTML context

Comment: @Chellappan that does not work

Comment: are you getting any error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it, it is very simple. Just write `'logo'`:

```
<div class="logo">
   <span class="logo-type"><img src="{{ 'logo' }}"></span>
</div>
```